# Export and save the datagridview Excel or Txt With a button

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to save a datagridview as a different excel or txt file every time I click the save button with using c#. How can I do that

Here is my codes. But it isn't working as I want.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This line of code creates a text file for the data export.
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\\Users\DiktaşHaftalikUretim\\table.txt");
        try
        {
            string sLine = "";

            //This for loop loops through each row in the table
            for (int r = 0; r <= dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; r++)
            {
                //This for loop loops through each column, and the row number
                //is passed from the for loop above.
                for (int c = 0; c <= dataGridView2.Columns.Count - 1; c++)
                {
                    sLine = sLine + dataGridView2.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value;
                    if (c != dataGridView2.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        //A comma is added as a text delimiter in order
                        //to separate each field in the text file.
                        //You can choose another character as a delimiter.
                        sLine = sLine + ",";
                    }
                }
                //The exported text is written to the text file, one line at a time.
                file.WriteLine(sLine);
                sLine = "";
            }

            file.Close();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Export Complete.", "Program Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (System.Exception err)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            file.Close();
        }

    }
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw6UP.png)

The datagridview I am using is below

Answer (score 0):

I am using interop.
First you need to add refercnce to interop excel, if you dont have already you need to download from Nuget.

[image]

```
          private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // creating Excel Application  
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            // creating new WorkBook within Excel application  
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            // creating new Excelsheet in workbook  
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
            // changing the name of active sheet  
            worksheet.Name = "Test";
            // storing header part in Excel  
            for (int i = 1; i < dgvData.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dgvData.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }
            // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet  
            for (int i = 0; i < dgvData.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dgvData.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            // save the application  
            workbook.SaveAs("YOUR_PATH\\Test.csv", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
       false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
       Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            // NOTE: if you want to open this file keep thouse line else remove thouse lines and remove the comment from the app.Quit();
            app.WindowState = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized;
            app.Visible = true;
            //// Exit from the application  
            //app.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Notice: if you want to open excel file right after you transfer the data delete the line app.Quit(); and add
app.Visible = true;

and the result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Added gif:

Comment: Thanks for helpful. I wrote this codes. And I added app.Visible= true. But it isn't open.

Comment: did you delete also the `app.Quit();`?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse :)

Comment: try also to add `app.WindowState = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWindowState.xlMaximized;` both should be located where app.Quit(); was in the code.

Comment: no, that didn't happen either. I have a few questions in my mind.
You want the first one to get the name of every excel file I save in a textbox field. I made worksheet.Name = textBox2.Text for this, is that enough?
Secondly, should there be an excel file called Test.xlsx in the path of the file I will save, according to the code you wrote? Should we do something special for the date format?

Comment: I update the code and added example with gif. For you other questions I would added logic for checking illigal characters and also Trim(). and for the path I would use two strings one with the path and one for the name of the file and use `Path.Combine()`

Comment: I'm adding a picture. I want to export selected rows. Could my problem be caused by this? Sorry for not explaining fully.

Comment: In that case you just need to add if statement to findout if the row checked or not.. if you need more help write your email

Comment: my head stopped, i can't progress in any way, i would be very grateful if you could help me    elifbaysar06@gmail.com please reach me

Answer (score 0):

If saving to Excel is `.xlsx` format, consider using [SpreadSheetLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpreadsheetLight/3.5.0?_src=template) which is added via NuGet package manager in Visual Studio.

- This example has a DateTime column which needs a style, if you do not have a DateTime column ignore this.
- After the data is imported, started at A1 the columns are auto-sized
- Use `document.RenameWorksheet(SLDocument.DefaultFirstSheetName,"TODO");` before SaveAs to rename the default WorkSheet.

Add this class to your project

```
using SpreadsheetLight;
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace Demo.Classes
{
    internal class ExcelOperations
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Save <see cref="DataTable"/> to an Excel file, in this case the 4th column is a Date so we
        /// need to format this column using a <see cref="SLStyle"/>
        /// <para></para>
        /// The data will start at A1
        /// <para></para>
        /// For the caller var (success, exception) = ExcelOperations.Export(dt, "SomeFile.xlsx");
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="table">DataTable to import into a new Excel file</param>
        /// <param name="fileName">File name to save data</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Success and Exception
        /// <para></para>
        /// When no errors, success is true and exception will be null, if not success, exception will
        /// contain the runtime exception
        /// </returns>
        public static (bool success, Exception exception) Export(DataTable table, string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var document = new SLDocument())
                {
                    SLStyle dateStyle = document.CreateStyle();
                    dateStyle.FormatCode = "mm-dd-yyyy";

                    // start at A1
                    document.ImportDataTable(1, SLConvert.ToColumnIndex("A"), table, true);

                    document.SetColumnStyle(4, dateStyle);
                    
                    // auto size columns
                    var stats = document.GetWorksheetStatistics();
                    for (int index = 0; index < stats.EndColumnIndex +1; index++)
                    {
                        document.AutoFitColumn(index);
                    }

                    document.SaveAs(fileName);

                    return (true, null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return (false, exception);
            }
        }
    }
}
```